# Reading a file in Python without an extension

Tags: python

I want to read a (basically a text file) file without an extension in Python 2.6. I have tried the following codes with the following errors..

```
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path + "Bookmarks",'*')):
    review_file = open(infile,'r').read()
    print review_file
```

-> global name glob is not defined

```
f = open(path, "r")
text = f.readlines()
print text
```

-> Prints "x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\" etc, and this is not what is inside of this file.

Edit: -> The conents of the file, directly, is what I want, for example if the file had "023492034blackriver0brydonmccluskey" in it, it would (as of now) extract it with a bunch of binary values, whereas I only want the exacy contents. How would I do so?

Comment: Open the file with a hex editor (or a decent text editor set to show non-printable characters). I bet you there are some NUL bytes in front of the text.

Answer (score 5):

1. If you want to use the `glob` module, you have to `import` it first:

   ```
   import glob
   for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*')):
       review_file = open(infile,'r').read()
       print review_file
   ```
2. Are you sure that your file does not contain the binary data you are getting?

Comment: I apologize if I made it appear differently in the first post, but I am attempting to read just straight text from the file (as I have now edited in the OP post).

Comment: I don't get it.  If your file contains non-printable characters such as NULL bytes `\x00`, do you want to read those?  Do you want to skip them until you find the first ASCII character?  What output do you expect when you `file.read()` from a file that contains `\x00\x00abc`, other than `\x00\x00abc`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it opening in text mode. But as per the documentation, 'r' should have been  synonym of 'rt'.

```
f = open(path, "rt")
text = f.readlines()
print text
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I just confirmed with the doc and made the changes to my answer

Comment: According to the documentation, there is no 't' mode.

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer: The reference is at http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html ('t' text mode (default)) for Python 3. I checked there are no release changes on this from 2.x version.

Comment: OK, sorry, I was only checking the docs for 2.7 (http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/functions.html#open). Nevertheless, using `'r'` or `'rt'` won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code looks at every file in the directory; if you only want files without an extension you should be using glob.glob('*.')

Comment: I apologize, I have edited it to the following: path + "Bookmarks"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from the OP, the question needs to be rephrased along the lines of "I have a file with NULs in it, how do I get rid of them so I only see the text". To which the answer would be something like:

```
with open("myfile", 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    clean_data = data.replace('\0', '')
    text = clean_data.decode('ascii') # Or other encoding, if text is not ASCII
```